# В каком виде хранить данные

Tags: python, база-данных

Начал разрабатывать CRM-систему для организации (системой будут пользоваться 20-30 человек) и встал вопрос в каком виде хранить данные. Данных будет не много (около 10 таблиц и в каждой таблице по 100-150 строк), но они будут часто изменяться и пересылаться между пользователями.

Изначально решил использовать json файлы и ftp соединение с хостом, чтобы можно было скачивать и отправлять на хост файлы, но в какой то момент понял, что возможно будет проще и удобнее использовать БД вместо json (из за того что в файлах очень часто будут изменения, в некоторых таблицах нужно считать сумму полей и добавлять графики).

Теперь перейду к вопросам :

1. Правильно ли я решил перейти от json к БД ?
2. Если переходить к БД то как лучше их использовать ? Создать на хосте базы данных и через ftp скачивать, изменять ее и потом отправлять обратно на хост или же создать базы данных на хосте и уже к ним удаленно подключаться и отправлять запросы (без скачивания)

Если где-то написал глупость то не судите строго. Первый раз берусь за такую задачу и первый раз пишу здесь свой вопрос.

Comment: Правильнее всё-таки подключаться всем к одной БД, они на это и рассчитаны, собственно. Ну, кроме совсем урезанных БД. Но всё-равно зависит от сценария использования - как там у пользователей с интернетом, хорошо ли, всегда ли они могут обратиться к БД на хосте.

Comment: Понял , спасибо.

Возник еще вопрос , какое количество пользователей одновременно может быть подключено к одной БД? Если допустим подключится одновременно 20 пользователей , БД даст сбой или нет? (думаю разместить БД в postgresql)

Comment: Серьёзные базы типа постгреса могут очень много подключений спокойно обрабатывать если всё правильно запрограммировать

Comment: Наверное стоит сразу предусмотреть доступ через web browser к страницам вашей CRM. Поэтому всю архитектуру следует сразу разрабатывать в этом разрезе, т.е. web-server, database-server, application-server (и не забудьте систему архивации на внешних носителях продумать)

Comment: А зачем продумывать доступ через браузер? Я планировал запаковать как приложение для ПК. На счет системы архивации согласен , этот момент я буду учитывать .

Comment: @Василек, браузер есть на любом компе. Этот подход значительно гибче, нежели специально устанавливаемая на комп отображалка. Все равно у вас бизнес-логика будет распределена между базой данных и исполняемыми приложениями. А вот синхронизировать приложения на одном сервере значительно проще, нежели на многих персоналках